# OR filter between table columns

Tags: excel, ms-access, filter

Is there a way to filter Excel tables similar to how Access queries can filter fields with OR operators?

E.g. I have the following table:
[image]
I want to list all items with the Messis aspect. In Access, one would make a query with Messis OR Messis OR Messis.. each in the following line or with OR in between. I would like to do something similar in Excel...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find the row(s) where text X appears in any one of several columns.  To do this, consider adding a column that is the concatenation of each column.  Then use the column filter to select rows that contain text X.

An example:
[image]

For Column 6:

[image]

Results in:

[image]

#### Alternate answer

If, on the other hand, you want the OR statement for a single column, you can use the OR feature of the AutoFilter.  If that doesn't appeal to you, you can use add a range outside of the table that includes has the text of a column in its first cell.  Put the possible text options in the cells immediately below.  Here's a picture:

[image: Advanced data analysis setup]

Then, with the cursor in your table, click on Data, Advanced and complete the dialog box as shown.

[image]

Click on OK to see:

[image]

Comment: I thought of a better way of doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203583/change-row-data-into-column-form?noredirect=1#comment35496299_23203583

   If I could get the data into columns, I can just filter for stuff like Messis >=1